# How to slice a list in Django template?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm doing some pagination in Django. I want to show the pages' number which are ahead of the current page. I am using the following code:

```
{% for page in blogs_page.paginator.page_range|slice:"0:{{ blogs_page.number }}" %}
```

But this seems useless; the result does the same as the following:

```
{% for page in blogs_page.paginator.page_range %}
```

The `slice` does not work here. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you want to show the next page number ?

Comment: You cannot render variables with `{{ }}` inside the argument to a filter - you'd need to generate that whole argument in the view, or use a custom template tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `{{ }}` inside of `{% %}`, don't do this `{% {{ }} %}`.

```
{% for page in blogs_page.paginator.page_range|slice:"0:blogs_page.number" %}
```

I think it won't work. If I were you I would create a custom tag and executed all the logic there. So, it will look like this:

**Template:**

```
{% custom_tag blogs_page as result %}
{% for page in result %}
```

**templatetags/tags.py:**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def custom_tag(bl_page):
    return bl.page.paginator.page_range[0:bl_page.number]
```

Details: [custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)